# Como redistribuir una aplicacion de C++ desarrollada en VS015 en Windows 8.1

Tags: c++

He desarrollado una aplicacion en C++ usando el VS2015 y con W8.1. Al ejecutar ela aplicacion en otras PC con W8.1 me da un error con ucrtbase.dll. Sin embargo, en PC com W10 la aplicacion corre sin problemas.
He probado instalar VCRedis_x64.exe y VCRedist_x86.exe update 3, no he obtenido ningun resultado favorable.
Alguna sugerencia
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando sobre UCRT he encontrado éste enlace donde Microsoft explica la introducción del Universal CRT: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Especialmente interesante la sección "Distributing Software that uses the Universal CRT". Citando la página:

> The Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component. It is a part of Windows 10. For Windows versions prior to Windows 10, the Universal CRT is distributed via Windows Update.

Básicamente, el fichero ucrtbase.dll es parte del sistema operativo, no del compilador. Según sugieren, instalando las últimas actualizaciones del sistema operativo debería solucionarlo. También está disponible aquí: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Según comentan:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 creates a dependency on the Universal CRT when applications are built by using the Windows 10 Software Development Kit

Ésta dependencia se añade al configurar Windows 10 como target de sistema operativo. Si quisieras eliminar la dependencia, deberías poder hacerlo ajustando el target del proyecto a una versión anterior de Windows.